# Import a custom validation function for use in the arguments block

Tags: matlab, syntax, argument-validation

I have a function file `my_function.m` that uses [function argument validation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-argument-validation-1.html):

```
function b = my_function(a)
    arguments
        a (1, 1) double {mustBeReal}
    end
    b = a + 1;
end
```

I have written a [custom validation function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/argument-validation-functions.html#mw_3e8f7e5b-fbb5-4725-be02-4751c675a92a) (as an example), in a namespaced package, so its fully qualified name is something like `mypackage.foo.mustBeSomething`.

I want to be able to [import](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) the name `mustBeSomething` immediately for use in the `arguments` block.

```
import mypackage.foo.mustBeSomething;
```

But MATLAB doesn't let me place it anywhere sane:

- Placing it in the first line before the `function` keyword causes MATLAB to interpret `my_function` as a local function
- Placing it in the line after `function` but before `arguments` causes MATLAB to complain that the arguments block must come first
- Placing it in after the `arguments` keyword but before the `a` line causes MATLAB to interpret `import` as an argument name

Is there really no way I can use just `mustBeSomething`, instead of the fully qualified name through an import?

```
function b = my_function(a)
    arguments
        a (1, 1) double {mustBeReal, mypackage.foo.mustBeSomething}
    end
    b = a + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Function Argument Validation documentation:

> ## Restrictions on Variable and Function Access
>
> arguments blocks exist in the function's workspace. Any packages, classes, or functions added to the scope of the function using the import command are added to the scope of the arguments block.

So you can just `import` in the function code block to use with the arguments block.

```
function b = my_function(a)
    arguments
        a (1, 1) double {mustBeReal, mustBeSomething}
    end
    import mypackage.foo.mustBeSomething
    b = a + 1;
end
```